# Can't connect to a remote Kafka producer from windows through java code

Tags: apache-kafka

i am trying to test my kafka producer code from windows eclipse to remote kafka producer(running in AWS Cloud) but i am getting error below i attached my code and error  I searched lot but still it is not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("metadata.broker.list", "52.74.109.118:9092");

    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    props.put("advertised.host.name", "kafka");
    // props.put("serializer.class",
    // com.funspot.utils.SerializerUtils.class);
    props.put("request.required.acks", "1");
    ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
    Producer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new Producer<String, String>(
            config);

    String msg = "hai";
    KeyedMessage<String, String> keyedMessage = new KeyedMessage<String, String>(
            "messaging.sms", msg);
    System.out.println(msg);

    kafkaProducer.send(keyedMessage);

    System.out.println("message sent");
}
```

The error log

```
 hai
[2015-05-13 19:21:13,968] ERROR fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed (kafka.utils.Utils$:106)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$1.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:67)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:67)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
    at com.ladooo.util.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:33)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
    ... 9 more
[2015-05-13 19:21:13,984] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler:97)
[2015-05-13 19:21:14,094] ERROR fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed (kafka.utils.Utils$:106)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
    at com.ladooo.util.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:33)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
    ... 9 more
[2015-05-13 19:21:14,094] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler:97)
[2015-05-13 19:21:14,203] ERROR fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed (kafka.utils.Utils$:106)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
    at com.ladooo.util.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:33)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
    ... 9 more
[2015-05-13 19:21:14,203] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler:97)
[2015-05-13 19:21:14,312] ERROR fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed (kafka.utils.Utils$:106)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
    at com.ladooo.util.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:33)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
    ... 9 more
[2015-05-13 19:21:14,312] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler:97)
[2015-05-13 19:21:14,421] ERROR fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed (kafka.utils.Utils$:106)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(messaging.sms)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:kafka,port:9092)] failed
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
    at com.ladooo.util.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:33)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
    ... 9 more
[2015-05-13 19:21:14,421] ERROR Failed to send requests for topics messaging.sms with correlation ids in [0,8] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler:97)
Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
    at com.ladooo.util.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:33)
```

Server.properties

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The port the socket server listens on
port=9092

# Hostname the broker will bind to. If not set, the server will bind to all interfaces
host.name=kafka

# Hostname the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, it uses the
# value for "host.name" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
# advertised.host.name=<>

# The port to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use. If this is not set,
# it will publish the same port that the broker binds to.
# advertised.port=<>

# The number of threads handling network requests
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads doing disk I/O
num.io.threads=8
# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma seperated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/home/ubuntu/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to exceessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################


# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log as long as the remaining
# segments don't drop below log.retention.bytes.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

# By default the log cleaner is disabled and the log retention policy will default to just delete segments after their retention expires.
# If log.cleaner.enable=true is set the cleaner will be enabled and individual logs can then be marked for log compaction.
log.cleaner.enable=false

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Comment: could you please share the server.properties file

Comment: Hi above i added my server.properties

Comment: do you have the host.name=kafka defined in /etc/hosts ? you can instead deine the machine ip there. also another thing you can try by un commenting the `advertised.host.name` and add your broker ip to see if it helps

Answer (score 6):

Issue got fixed 
Added the line in the server.properties inside the kafka config
`advertised.host.name=ec2<ip>ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com`  (you have to give fully qualified name of ec2 machine) and restart the zookeeper and kafka.

But this working fine between two physical machine without even giving the following property

```
advertised.host.name
```

Comment: I am going to add a jira to actually log the node that cannot be connected to instead of adding the useless error in its current form which fails to communicate this. This is just a case of sloppy programming.

Comment: For Kafka 2.12 the propery is `advertised.listeners` sample value `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.142.134:9092`